# How to format correctly my URl for using graph APi filter

Tags: groovy, azure-active-directory

I have the following Url graph APi that works as expected in POSTMAN :

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail eq 'myuser@hotmail.com'

When I pass theis URl to graph API using groovy script, I get the following error :

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 52: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=mail eq 'myuser@gmail.com'

Here is the sample code how I build the URl :

```
 String _url =graph_base_user_url + '?\$filter=mail eq ' + "'" + userEmail + "'"

 def http = new HTTPBuilder(java.net.URLEncoder.encode(_url, "UTF-8"))
```

=====> UPDATED =======
I have apply the following change to my method, I do not have any more the error but what is strange is that return json content all my user instead of a single records. Here is below my method

```
Thnaks for your reply,
```

I have a wierd issue, when I try the filter in POSTMAN, it return the correct record based on the provided email

but when I use it in groovy script, it return my all users instead of the filter record,

here is my method below :

```
public String getUserIdByEmailQuery(String AuthToken,String userEmail){

     String _ret

         def http = new HTTPBuilder(graph_base_user_url +"?")
         http.request(GET) {

             requestContentType = ContentType.JSON
             query:[ $filter:"mail eq '$userEmail'" ]

             headers.'Authorization' = "Bearer " + AuthToken    

             response.success = { resp, json ->
                 //_userId=json["id"].toString()
                 _ret=json
             }

             // user ID not found : error 404
             response.'404' = { resp ->       
                 _ret = 'Not Found'
             }

         }
         _ret
     }
```

My method parameter graph_base_user_url is equal to "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"

Any idea why it returns all users instead of filter record ?
Note that I have cross check the usermail in the parameter ans it is correct and exist

Thanks for help
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the HTTPBuilder the idiomatic way:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder( graph_base_user_url )
def result = http.get( query:[ $filter:"mail eq '$userEmail'" ] )
```

UPDATE:

your code is not passing query params properly. It should be:

```
        def http = new HTTPBuilder(graph_base_user_url)
         http.request(GET) {
             ...
             uri.query = [ $filter:"mail eq '$userEmail'", $select:id ] 
             ...
        }
```

Comment: I have try to implement and what is happening is that it returns all my users instead of filter one. I check that email is correct. See my update in post

Comment: thanks it return a single record data now. How can i combine in the querry script a select statment wich wil return only the Id field as below in POSTMAN?

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail eq 'user1.tom@gmail.com'&$select=id

Comment: I have tried but get a script error as :
"expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway @ line 176, column 74. eq '$userEmail', $select:id ]"

Comment: looks like you deleted `"` so your code does not compile

Comment: oups sorry I correct it now but I get an other error saying :
"groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: id"

Comment: then you have to define the `id` somewhere

Comment: Ok I forget the select filter, I can at least return a single uers record, thanks for your great help on this